# Why naive bayes text classifier is performing poor while using labeled categories?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I am trying to create a text classification model using multinomial naive bayes. My data is having 10 different types of category. During model training i have represented these categories in integer format.

```
topics = ["gis","security","photo","mathematica","unix","wordpress","scifi","electronics","android","apple"]
topic2label = {topics[i]:i for i in range(len(topics))}
```

**Training Data format:**

```
{"topic":"electronics","question":"What is the effective differencial effective of this circuit","excerpt":"I'm trying to work out, in general terms, the effective capacitance of this circuit .  \n\nWhat is the effective capacitance of this circuit and will the ...\r\n        "}
{"topic":"electronics","question":"Heat sensor with fan cooling","excerpt":"Can I know which component senses heat or acts as heat sensor in the following circuit?\nIn the given diagram, it is said that the 4148 diode acts as the sensor. But basically it is a zener diode and ...\r\n        "}
```

**This is how my code snippet looks like:**

```
# ---------------------------------------- Training -------------------------------------
import sklearn
with open('training.json') as f:
    next(f)
        for line in f:
            data = json.loads(line)
            topic.append(data["topic"])
            que = data["question"]
            question.append(data["question"])
            excer = data["excerpt"]
            excerpt.append(data["excerpt"])
            combo.append(que +" "+ excer)

unique_topics = list(set(topic))
numeric_topics = [name.replace('gis', '1').replace('security', '2').replace('photo', '3').replace('mathematica', '4').replace('unix', '5').replace('wordpress', '6').replace('scifi', '7').replace('electronics', '8').replace('android', '9').replace('apple', '10') for name in new_topic]
x1 = np.array(question)
x2 = np.array(excerpt)
x3 = np.array(combo)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, ngram_range=(1,2),stop_words="english") 
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(x3)
Y = np.array(new_topic)
clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.1).fit(X, Y)

# ----------------------------   Prediction -----------------------------------------

docs_new = []

input = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(input):
    input_data = raw_input()
    data = json.loads(input_data)
    que = data["question"]
    excer = data["excerpt"]
    docs_new.append(que +" "+ excer)

X_new_counts = vectorizer.transform(docs_new)
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_counts)
predicted =  list(predicted)
for i in predicted:
    print i
```

Now i analysed a weird behaviour, while using integer representation of categories the accuracy of my model is 82% and if i am using the string representation the accuracy surge to 90%.

My question is why model is behaving different (better) in second situation ?

P.S. I am using sklearn library.

Comment: Can you give the exact code you used? There should not be any difference between using strings as labels or integers as labels.

Comment: what do you mean by concretely by poor performance? what is the size of your training set? are the classes balanced?

Comment: you could just have used ``LabelEncoder`` to get from strings to numeric labels. Try that if you like. What is the type of new_topic?

Comment: the data type of new_topic is list ..